# How to turn off validation for disabled fieldset in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a form array in the parent form. I want to disable the form array based on the condition. I had defined a form array inside a `fieldset`. so that I can easily disable that form array. But after disabling the `fieldset` the form array still firing validations for the nested form controls.

Html Code:

```
<form [formGroup]="quoteForm"> 
    <ng-container formArrayName="parts">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let part of partsControls.controls; let partIndex=index" [formGroupName]="partIndex">   
            <div class="py-2" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <h4 class="m-0 font-15 width-full">
                    {{part.value.partNo}}
                </h4>
                <span fxflex="auto"></span>
                <div class="ml-2 green-bg">
                    <mat-label>No Quote</mat-label>
                    <mat-checkbox formControlName="isNoQuote"
                        fxLayoutGap="12px"
                        [checked]="part.value.isNoQuote"
                        (change)="onChangeNoQuote($event.checked, part)"
                        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                        class="ml-2">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                </div>
                <span fxFlex="auto"></span>
                <span class="quote-amount-ac green-bg font-15">
                    {{finishedComponentGroupControl(partIndex).value.totalCostPerPart
                        |currency:currencyCode:'symbol-narrow':'.3'}}
                </span>
            </div>
            <fieldset [disabled]="part.value.isNoQuote">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="rfq-box-small">
                            <span class="rfq-heading black-font">Part
                                No</span>
                            <span
                                class="rfq-conten-box green-font rfq-conten-box">{{part.value.partNo}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="rfq-box-small">
                            <span class="rfq-heading black-font">Annual
                                Quantity</span>
                            <span class="rfq-conten-box">
                                {{part.value.quantity}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ng-container formGroupName="finishedComponent">
                        <div class="col-md-4">

                            <mat-form-field fxFlex="auto">
                                <mat-label>Min Order Qty</mat-label>
                                <input matInput type="text"
                                    formControlName="minOrderQuantity"
                                    autocomplete="off" digitOnly>

                                <mat-error
                                    *ngFor="let validation of validationMessages.minOrderQuantity">
                                    <mat-error class="error-message"
                                        *ngIf="finishedComponentGroupControl(partIndex).controls.minOrderQuantity.hasError(validation.type) && (submitted || finishedComponentGroupControl(partIndex).controls.minOrderQuantity.dirty || finishedComponentGroupControl(partIndex).controls.minOrderQuantity.touched)">
                                        {{validation.message}}</mat-error>
                                </mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
 </form>
```

TS Code:

```
validationMessages = { 
    'minOrderQuantity': [
      { type: 'min', message: 'Min Order Qty must be greater then 0.' },
      { type: 'max', message: 'Min Order Qty should not be more then 999999999.' },
    ],
}

this.quoteForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    parts: this.formBuilder.array([])
});

newPart(): FormGroup {
   const group: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      partNo: [null],
      quantity: [null],
      isNoQuote: [null],
      finishedComponent: this.formBuilder.group({
        minOrderQuantity: [null, [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(999999999)]]
      })
  })
}

get formsControls() { return this.quoteForm.controls; }

get partsControls(): FormArray {
    return this.quoteForm.get("parts") as FormArray
}

public finishedComponentGroupControl(itemIndex: number): FormGroup {
    return this.partsControls.controls[itemIndex].get("finishedComponent") as FormGroup;
}
```

I tried many ways but could not solve the issue. Can anyone help me?

Comment: for such big questions always produce stackblitz if you want the answer quickly

Comment: Providing stackblitz link would be good otherwise difficult to trace.

Comment: if you "disable" one FormControl Angular don't check it. But for disabled the formControl or a FormArray you should use disable and enable method -not work use [attrb.disable]. You can use a directive to disable the FormControl

Answer (score 0):

You might try to clear validators at some point - maybe when your check shows that fieldset should be disabled:

```
this.partsControls.controls.forEach( (control, i) => {
    this.partsControls.controls[i].clearValidators();
});
this.partsControls.updateValueAndValidity();
```

(or try the same for this.quoteForm instead of this.partsControls).